# I'm looking for a way to remove select option after its pushed to array in angular 2+

Tags: arrays, angular, loops, ngfor

I need a way to remove from select list the element after its been added to array, not allowing it to be inserted again, this is the dropdown:

```
<div class="modal-body">
      <select class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" id="ddlGrupos" name="user Selecionado" [(ngModel)]="userSelected" (change)="selectValorUsuario(userSelected)">
        <option *ngFor="let usuario of Usuario" [ngValue]="usuario">{{usuario.nome}}</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

and this is the push method who must remove from list after been pushed:

```
adicionarArrUsuario() {
   const result = this.unidadeUsuarioArr.some(t => t.id === this.usuarioObjectSelect.id);
   if (!result) {
      this.unidadeUsuarioArr.push({
      id: this.usuarioObjectSelect.id,
      nome: this.usuarioObjectSelect.nome
     });
   }
}
```

Comment: perhaps you can `disable` the `option` if it's added into array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the element upon a selection using [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
selectValorUsuario(userSelected) {
   this.Usuario = this.Usuario.filter(usuario => usuario.id !== userSelected.id);        
}
```

Apply this approach to your logic.